# how to take android full backup using adb

Tags: android, shell, cmd, adb, android-backup-service

I'm trying to take full backup using "adb backup -all -f path" and it took backup and stored in my PC.

When i try to restore it using "adb restore path" then it restored into the target device.

ADB backup command is not taking backup of messages, contacts and pictures. Kindly guide me if im missing something.

I could see that i have to use "adb root" to take backup using pull command. **Will the device warranty be there if i use adb root command?**

Thanks you with anticipation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but about product warranty

Answer (score 1):

if you root your device, it won't be under warranty anymore.
Few applications actually don't allow backup by setting`android:alloweBackup = "false"` in android manifest file.This is true for both message and contacts. Also it depends on which version of android you have. [You can see this AndroidManifest.xml file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/+refs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply But Then how does MDM tools like [MobileGo](http://mobilego.wondershare.com/)  and [MobileEdit](http://www.mobiledit.com/) do this seamlessly

Comment: since messages and contacts is stored in contentproviders so application works.

Comment: sorry.. i don't get you. if an application take this then or why adb cant get it

Comment: APIs are porvided to access database but adb can't access as allowBackup is false